# Como bloquear um item de uma listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho uma lista de *TextView* em uma *ListView*, e ao clicar em um dos *TextView* tenho acesso a um *Fragment*.
Como faço para, quando estiver em um *Fragment*, o *TextView* responsável por abri-lo seja bloqueado? Sendo assim, o aplicativo não será forçado a abrir o mesmo *Fragment* repetidamente!

Comment: Está um pouco confusa a pergunta. Será isto que procura: `textView.setEnabled(false); `?

Comment: Quero evitar que o usuário possa clicar duas vezes em um mesmo item da listview, não importa s é um textview... No meu caso é simplesmente um ArrayList de String!

Comment: Se não me engano, o `BaseAdapter` tem um método que você pode sobreescrever e dizer se o item está habilitado, dê uma olhada no método `isEnabled`. Acho que ele servirá pra o que precisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java view.setClickable(Boolean.FALSE);` dentro do método onClick da sua listView:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View rootView, int pos, long id) {
        // hard processing
        ...
        rootView.setClickable(Boolean.FALSE);
        ...
       // More hard processing
    }
```